# Clear DNS Domain with systemd-resolve on Linux

Tags: ubuntu

*resolvectl* can clear a DNS Domain set to "~."

```
$ resolvectl domain
Global:
Link 3 (ens192): ~. <--

$ sudo resolvectl domain ens192 ""

$ resolvectl domain
Global:
Link 3 (ens192):  <--
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 which doesn't have *resolvectl*. My only choice is *systemd-resolve* but I'm unable to clear the DNS domain:

```
$ sudo systemd-resolve --interface=ens192 --set-domain=""
Failed to set domain configuration: Root domain is not suitable as search domain
```

I want to remove the DNS Domain for a given interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `sudo resolvectl revert $LINK`
You can get LINK from `resolvectl dns`